# How To get Multidimensional Input Fields Array Index with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This my sample HTML form with multidimensional input fields

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="diameter[0][top]" type="text" id="diameter_top0" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
    <td><input name="diameter[0][bottom]" type="text" id="diameter_bottom0" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="diameter[1][top]" type="text" id="diameter_top1" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
    <td><input name="diameter[1][bottom]" type="text" id="diameter_bottom1" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="diameter[5][top]" type="text" id="diameter_top5" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
    <td><input name="diameter[5][bottom]" type="text" id="diameter_bottom5" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
</tr>
```

Lets say I'm writing on ID `diameter_bottom5` input. And onkeyup I need index of `diameter` of input field. In this example it would be 5.

I don't want to use `regex` or `slice` in `name` or `id` attribute.

I don't want to create custom attribute to store index.

How can get multidimensional input fields array index in which I'm currently typing using JavaScript?

Comment: indexes are hard coded ?

Comment: yeh it will be generated by server side code to avoid duplication's

Comment: as your indexes are hardcoded, only option you have is to pick it from name or id attributes

Comment: what if it isn't? how would you do it? (don't mention whole code, just give me an idea)

Comment: create a data attribute at the same time as you are creating the id.... <input name="diameter[5][top]" type="text" data-index="5" .... then you can simply get the data attribute on the keyup

Comment: @FaizanRupani, if it would be dynamic, I would add an ` onkeyup` and will pass index to it's callback as argument

Comment: Thank you all I'm back to custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are O.K. with the 'order index' of your table data, you can do it like that (obviously, this wouldn't work if your 'numbering' won't match given order and/or amount of inputs):

```js
const tableData = [...document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('td')]

tableData.forEach((item, i) => item.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  console.log(i)
}), false);
```

```html
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="diameter[0][top]" type="text" id="diameter_top0" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
    <td><input name="diameter[0][bottom]" type="text" id="diameter_bottom0" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="diameter[1][top]" type="text" id="diameter_top1" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
    <td><input name="diameter[1][bottom]" type="text" id="diameter_bottom1" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="diameter[5][top]" type="text" id="diameter_top5" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
    <td><input name="diameter[5][bottom]" type="text" id="diameter_bottom5" size="5" class="diameter" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's the thing I want to number my indexes. Looks like I have to go back to custom attribute

Comment: Yes, you probably would. If you'd have a data attribute containing only a number, it would be easy to do.